# Parametrization of Plucker Equations for Grassmannian $Gr(2,n)$ by ordered quadruples

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, grassmannians

As David Speyer pointed out in a comment to this MO question, [Number of Plücker relations for a Grassmannian](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230710/number-of-pl%c3%bccker-relations-for-a-grassmannian),
'many people mean specific lists of relations when they say "the Plucker relations"'.

I'm looking for a reference to the parametrization of the set of Plucker equations for the Grassmannian $Gr(2,n)$ by ordered 4-sets of indexes. Here is a precise theorem:

Point $x$ belongs to $Gr(2,n)$ *iif* its Plucker coordinates $\Delta_{a,b}$ satisfy the Plucker equation

$$ \Delta_{i,k} \Delta_{j,l} = \Delta_{i,j} \Delta_{k,l} + \Delta_{i,l} \Delta_{j,k} $$
 for  every ordered quadruple $1 \leq i < j < k < l \leq n$.

> Is there a paper that explicitly mentions such a parametrization? If not, what might be an illuminating passage from the standard parametrizations to the one above?

Comment: This theorem is precisely stated (for all $Gr(k,n)$ or $G/B$) and proved in several textbooks, for example Fulton's Young Tableaux, or Miller and Sturmfels's Combinatorial Commutative Algebra.